# In Java is it possible to get a directory file listing inside a WAR classpath using a resource path?

Tags: java, file, jakarta-ee, file-io, java-6

I have a list of files in a directory on the classpath that I need to read, and would prefer using the File API, but it appears I can't do that within an archive. This works on my local environment unit test, but when I deploy as a WAR inside an EAR, the listing of the files returns null:

```
File dir = new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("mydir").getPath());
File[] files = dir.listFiles();
```

Comment: How would I get a list of files from the input stream? I don't know their names, which is why I need a listing of actual File objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the File API when the war isn't unpacked, but you can use the Servlet API.

The [getResourcePaths](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResourcePaths%28java.lang.String%29) method of ServletContext can be used to retrieve all members of a "directory", and then [getResource](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) or [getResourceAsStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) to retrieve the contents of a file in the directory.

```
for (String s : context.getResourcePaths("foo")) {
    InputStream contents = context.getResourceAsStream(s);
    //do something with the contents
}
```

Comment: I thought that might be the case. If anywhere, do you know where in the Java docs this is stated (regarding a file listing for an unpacked WAR)?

Comment: Nowhere explicitly (that I know of) in javadoc. It's a consequence of the fact that a servlet engine is not obligated to place the contents of the WAR on the filesystem at all. That nugget is mentioned in the Servlet JSR, but I don't have a specific citation in javadoc for you — not everything is in javadoc.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Java SE 7 try:

```
Path jarPath = Paths.get(...);
try (FileSystem jarFS = FileSystems.newFileSystem(jarPath, null)) {
    Path dirJarPath = jarFS.getPath("/foo/mydir");
    <use a FileVisitor and Files.walkFileTree>
}
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileVisitor.html

Comment: @Puce: How would you even obtain the path to the jar file when the ear containing the war isn't unpacked? Doing that in a portable fashion isn't exactly straightforward. Even if it was, I'm worried that repeatedly uncompressing the jar file won't be very performant.

Comment: @SeanReilly Recently, I've added a utility method to the SoftSmithy Utility Library to get the jar of a class, but I haven't released it yet. You can find the code here (license: CDDL): http://softsmithy.hg.sourceforge.net/hgweb/softsmithy/lib/main-golden/file/058faa0f7621/lib-core/src/main/java/org/softsmithy/lib/nio/file/JarFiles.java
About the performance: you will have to profile it if there is an issue

Comment: @Sean Reilly: you don’t need the path to the jar file when you have a URL pointing to a resource inside it. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36021165/2711488) for a complete example…