# How to copy file into another directory in Java 8?

Tags: java, nio

I want to copy file from one package to another package.

I tried `Files.copy` method but it replaces my folder with copied file.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    InputStream in = CopyFileToDirectoryTest.class.getClassLoader()
            .getResourceAsStream("com/stackoverflow/main/Movie.class");

    Path path = Paths.get("D://folder");

    long copy = Files.copy(in, path,StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    System.out.println(copy);

}
```

This doesn't work because it deletes folder and creates file with the name of folder.

Is there a way in Java 8 or I should use [Apache Commons IO](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Files.copy` needs the name of the target file.

```
Path targetFilePath = Paths.get("D:/folder/Movie.class");
```

This is indeed requires a bit more than the conventional *"if the target is a directory, copy the file into it."* On the otherhand a quite useful requirement: an InputStream no longer has a name.

Comment: Thank you, but how to convert classpath resource(`com/stackoverflow/json/Movie.class`) to `Path` object?

Comment: Because I need to copy Movie.class from one package into another inside the same project.

Comment: @JaySmith: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15713119/java-nio-file-path-for-a-classpath-resource

Comment: A .class maintains its package path in its full class name. So that will not work normally. If you are repackaging classes from a jar, there are more regular means.

Comment: Thanks the link helped but it throws new exception `java.nio.file.DirectoryNotEmptyException`. Meaning `com/stackoverflow/json` is not empty.

Comment: I posted new question about this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43972777/exception-in-thread-main-java-nio-file-invalidpathexception-illegal-char