# java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 2:

Tags: java, nio

I have to copy classpath resource from one package to another.

My program is:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {

            ClassLoader classLoader = CopyFileToDirectoryTest.class.getClassLoader();
InputStream in = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("com/stackoverflow/main/Movie.class");

            URI uri = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("com/stackoverflow/json").toURI();
            Path path = Paths.get(uri.getPath(),"Movie.class");
            System.out.println(path);

            long copy = Files.copy(in, path, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
            System.out.println(copy);

        }
```

At `Files.copy` method I get exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 2: /D:/Programs/workspaceEE/HibernateDemo/target/classes/com/stackoverflow/json
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.normalize(WindowsPathParser.java:182)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:153)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:77)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.parse(WindowsPath.java:94)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.getPath(WindowsFileSystem.java:255)
    at java.nio.file.Paths.get(Paths.java:84)
    at com.stackoverflow.main.CopyFileToDirectoryTest.main(CopyFileToDirectoryTest.java:34)
```

How to solve it?

**Solution**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
        ClassLoader classLoader = CopyFileToDirectoryTest.class.getClassLoader();
        InputStream in = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("com//stackoverflow//main//Movie.class");
        URI uri = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("com//stackoverflow//json").toURI();
        String mainPath = Paths.get(uri).toString();
        Path path = Paths.get(mainPath, "Movie.class");
        System.out.println(path);
        long copy = Files.copy(in, path, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        System.out.println(copy);
    }
```

This code correctly copies `Movie.class` from package `com/stackoverflow/main` into `com/stackoverflow/json`.

Comment: This doesn't work because your classpath is composed of transparent and **opaque** resources - such as those inside a `jar`. You are trying to write to a path that looks something like `jar:file:/com/stackoverflow/json`, which is an invalid `Path` or `File` but a valid URI. In general, you cannot write to the classpath, only read from it.

Comment: No jar it is maven project

Comment: When you compile a Maven project it will generate a jar. How else would you distribute your compiled code? (Pre Java 9 that is)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java NIO file path issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9834776/java-nio-file-path-issue)

Answer (score 70, accepted):

problem is that `Paths.get()` doesn't expect that kind of value which is generated from `uri.getPath()`.

Solution:

```
URI uri = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("com/stackoverflow/json").toURI();
String mainPath = Paths.get(uri).toString();
Path path = Paths.get(mainPath ,"Movie.class");
```

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
Path path = new File(getClass()
.getResource("/<path to the image in your build/classes folder>")
.getFile()).toPath();
```

to get the correct path. Worked for me after several hours trying to find out why I couldn't get the file from the jar. This works for NetBeans 8.02

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue and got the exception, noticed there was a space in the filename, so I had to trim it. After that, the issue is resolved.

```
Path filePath = Paths.get(dirPathStr, newFileName.trim());
```

Answer (score 3):

After trying many times, this worked for me

```
      Path path = new File(getClass().getResource("/data.json").getFile()).toPath();
```

Now you can use your path as you wish e.g

```
        Reader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(path);
```

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem which I was facing from the past two days and finally, I got it
Space causes such problem 
try to solve

```
var fileName=YourFileName.trim();
Path filePath = Paths.get(dirPathStr, fileName);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error

> ./gradlew build

> 2023-04-10T16:56:54.855+02:00  INFO 10476 --- [           main]
> c.v.s.d.m.a.VogellaApplication           : No active profile set,
> falling back to 1 default profile: "default" Exception in thread
> "main" java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Trailing char < > at index
> 27: com.vogella.spring.di.model
> at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.normalize(WindowsPathParser.java:191)
> at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:153)
> at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:77)
> at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.parse(WindowsPath.java:92)

I analyzed the filenames and the configuration.
I noticed a space in the 'group' property in build.gradle file

```
group = 'com.vogella.spring.di.model '
```

I removed the extra space and the build command worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

The following solutions work correctly:

Solution1:

```
String logFileLocalPath = "../log/log.txt";
File logFile = new File(getURL(logFileLocalPath).getPath());
```

Solution 2:

```
File logFile = new 
File(Paths.get(getURL(logFileLocalPath).toURI()).toString());
```

---

```
private static URL getURL(String localPath) {

      return Main.class.getResource(localPath);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue while using extentReports in my automation, i simply corrected the report path

```
public void config() {
    String path = System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\reports\\index.html";       
    ExtentSparkReporter reporter = new ExtentSparkReporter(path);
    reporter.config().setReportName("Web Automation Reports");
    reporter.config().setDocumentTitle("Web Results");
```

...
}

Answer (score 0):

```
I faced this issue while working on microservices application

package com.test.employeeapp;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.EnableFeignClients;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableFeignClients(basePackages = "com.test.employeeapp.feignclient ")
public class EmployeeServiceApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(EmployeeServiceApplication.class, args);
}

}
in basePackages where have by mistake placed one extra space I just removed it 
and it worked
so what I suggest that just cross check once any extra space is added.
```