# Java NIO can't read files from JRT image

Tags: java, nio, java-11, java-module

When we create Java runtime by jlink it takes all java classes/resources and places them into JRT image file: `lib/modules`.

Here is basic Maven project resources structure I use:

```
src
  main
    resources
      dict
        xkcd_en
```

I'm just trying to read `xkcd_en` text file. If we look into JRT file, here it is:

```
>> jimage list /path/to/lib/modules
...
Module: main
    dict/xkcd_en
...
```

Also I've explicitly opened it in `module-info`, just in case:

```
module main {
    opens dict;
    // ..rest code omitted
}
```

The only way I could read the file is obtaining it as input stream:

**WORKS:**

```
public static InputStream getResourceAsStream(String resource) {
    return FileUtils.class.getResourceAsStream(resource);
}

System.out.println(new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(getResourceAsStream("/dict/xkcd_en")))
            .lines().collect(Collectors.joining("\n"))
);
```

**DOESN'T WORK:**

But if I'm trying to get the file URI and read it via Java NIO API, it doesn't work:

```
public static URL getResourceOrThrow(String resource) {
    URL url = FileUtils.class.getResource(resource);
    Objects.requireNonNull(url);
    return url;
}
```

1 - Java NIO can't find the file. But it definitely does exist, otherwise `getResource()` returns `null`.

```
System.out.println(Paths.get(getResourceOrThrow("/dict/xkcd_en").toURI()));
// /main/dict/xkcd_en

Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(getResourceOrThrow("/dict/xkcd_en").toURI()));

Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /main/dict/xkcd_en
        at java.base/jdk.internal.jrtfs.JrtFileSystem.checkNode(JrtFileSystem.java:494)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.jrtfs.JrtFileSystem.getFileContent(JrtFileSystem.java:253)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.jrtfs.JrtFileSystem.newInputStream(JrtFileSystem.java:342)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.jrtfs.JrtPath.newInputStream(JrtPath.java:631)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.jrtfs.JrtFileSystemProvider.newInputStream(JrtFileSystemProvider.java:322)
```

2 - The same if you'll use `FileSystem` directly:

```
FileSystem fs = FileSystems.getFileSystem(URI.create("jrt:/"));
System.out.println(fs.getPath("main/dict/xkcd_en"));
// main/dict/xkcd_en

Files.readAllLines(fs.getPath("main/dict/xkcd_en")));

Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /main/dict/xkcd_en
    at java.base/jdk.internal.jrtfs.JrtFileSystem.checkNode(JrtFileSystem.java:494)
```

3 - Java NIO doesn't even know what `jrt:/` scheme is.

```
Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(getResourceOrThrow("/dict/xkcd_en").toExternalForm()));

Caused by: java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 3: jrt:/main/dict/xkcd_en
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.normalize(WindowsPathParser.java:182)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:153)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:77)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.parse(WindowsPath.java:92)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.getPath(WindowsFileSystem.java:229)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Path.of(Path.java:147)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Paths.get(Paths.java:69)
```

Here is the [specs](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/220) of JRT FS.

> A jrt URL is a hierarchical URI, per RFC 3986, with the syntax
>
> jrt:/[$MODULE[/$PATH]]
>
> where $MODULE is an optional module name and $PATH, if present, is the
> path to a specific class or resource file within that module. The
> meaning of a jrt URL depends upon its structure:
>
> - jrt:/$MODULE/$PATH refers to the specific class or resource file named $PATH within the given $MODULE.
> - jrt:/$MODULE refers to all of the class and resource files in the module $MODULE.
> - jrt:/ refers to the entire collection of class and resource files stored in the current run-time image.

So obtained path looks ok to me. Where am I wrong?

Comment: There is a bug in the jrt file system provider, see: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8216553  You can work around it by prefixing the file path with "/modules". Also just to point out that your example using toExternalForm invoke Paths.get(String) which is for converting a path string to a file on the platform file system, not jrtfs.

Comment: @AlanBateman I thought, someone must have already reported this. I should have checked the bug database. After all, I added a work-around to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36021165/2711488) more than a year ago, so I suppose, I know this bug even longer.

Comment: @AlanBateman Is it just the conversion from `URI` to `Path` that's the bug or is the `modules` directory supposed to be "transparent" to users of jrtfs?

Comment: It's the URL -> jrt Path conversion that has an issue. The modules directory is important for users of jrtfs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## JRT File System

The part of the JEP you quote deals specifically with URLs. If you read on a little further you'll find where it discusses the JRT file system:

> A built-in NIO `FileSystem` provider for the `jrt` URL scheme ensures that development tools can enumerate and read the class and resource files in a run-time image by loading the `FileSystem` named by the URL `jrt:/`, as follows:
>
> ```java
> FileSystem fs = FileSystems.getFileSystem(URI.create("jrt:/"));
> byte[] jlo = Files.readAllBytes(fs.getPath("modules", "java.base",
>                                           "java/lang/Object.class"));
> ```
>
> **The top-level `modules` directory** *[emphasis added]* in this filesystem contains one subdirectory for each module in the image. **The top-level `packages` directory** *[emphasis added]* contains one subdirectory for each package in the image, and that subdirectory contains a symbolic link to the subdirectory for the module that defines that package.

As you can see, the JRT file system has two directories directly under the root: `modules` and `packages`. These were added as part of [JDK-8066492](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8066492) and their purpose is described by that issue. So the problem is not that the NIO API cannot read resources in a JRT image. The problem is that:

```
/main/dict/xkcd_en
```

Really does not exist. The resource is actually located at:

```
/modules/main/dict/xkcd_en
```

---

## JRT URLs

A JRT URL takes one of three forms (all mentioned in the part of the JEP you quote in your question):

1. `jrt:/$MODULE/$PATH`
2. `jrt:/$MODULE`
3. `jrt:/`

The first form is for accessing specific resources in the JRT image and the one we care about. As you can see, the URL does not include the top-level directories mentioned above. You can think of the URL as always being relative to the `modules` directory.

---

## JRT File System Provider Bug

That said, as [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54140750/java-nio-cant-read-files-from-jrt-image#comment95119300_54140750) by [@Alan Bateman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7463126/alan-bateman), you are encountering a bug. When you have a JRT URL and you try to convert it into a `Path` you *should* be getting a `Path` which points to an existing file. The problem is this conversion does not take the `modules` directory into account.

This bug was fixed in Java 13 by [JDK-8224946](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8224946).

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation. I think as API user I shoudn't care how exactly filesystem stores its data internally. If URL was resolved successfully then it must be possible to use it for access to corresonding resource.

Comment: According to the issue Alan Bateman linked in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54140750/java-nio-cant-read-files-from-jrt-image/54142975?noredirect=1#comment95119300_54140750), it appears that at least some of this behavior is a bug.