# Referencing packages in java without using String

Tags: java, reflection, package

Is there a way to reference a package in java in code without using a String?

Let me explain myself:

I've a function that fetches all object contained in a package, but I've to reference that package using a String, lets say "com.google.guava". This works, however, If I change the package name, the IDE is not able to automatically refractor the references, or if the package is external and dissapears after a major version change it is not detected at compile time.

With classes, I'd use a Class object directly when possible or Class#getName if what I need is a String representing the FQDN of the class, but I don't know if there's a way to do so with packages.

Sometimes I just do

```
Class<?> clazz = Foo.class;
Package p = clazz.getPackage();
```

This is more a curiosity than a real issue, I usually just reference by String and write a junit test in order to detect nom-existant packages used this way

Comment: `Foo.class.getPackage()` is already the best you can get. But “all object contained in a package” makes no sense. A package contains classes, not objects.

Comment: @Holger Well, I get config files and other stuff, I know they're not conceptually in the package (concerning to Java), but they're in the same directory and the package is the way I use to find the folder. English is not my mother languaje and I wanted to keep the post as simple as possible. My function returns all java property files, xml configs and classes (it is for a code generator, the function gets the existing generated files in order to update them. I know they should be in a specific resources folder, but I'm inheriting a bad project structure :(). This question was mostly curiosity

Comment: I don’t think that resources have to be in a specific resources folder. But if you mean “resources” you should not have said “object”. When you want to access resources, there is no point in getting the `Package` object, as the class `Package` does not offer anything for resource lookup. The `Package` class only exists to allow accessing meta information. Resources have to be accessed via `Foo.class.getResource(…)` anyway. The standard way to iterate over all resources, is [to open a filesystem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36021165/2711488).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of the following ways to get a `Package` object:

1. Call `classLoader.getPackage(java.lang.String)` or `Package.getPackage(java.lang.String)`.  These methods are deprecated.
2. Call `Package classLoader.getDefinedPackage(java.lang.String)`
3. Call `Package class.getPackage()`
4. Call `Package[] Package.getPackages()` and then scan through the resulting array for the one that you want.

The last two approaches qualify as finding a `Package` with using a `String`.

There is no equivalent to a Java "class literal" (i.e. `SomeClass.class`) for packages.

Comment: All solutions have the same "problem", however, the "There is no equivalent to a Java "class literal" (i.e. SomeClass.class) for packages." part answers my question. Thank you.