# SQLite database error in packaged executable but works in debug

Tags: java, database, sqlite, javafx

I'm not able to connect to my sqlite database in my packaged java application. It works perfectly in development. I'm using gradle jlink and jpackage to create a Windows executable. The application installs successfully but I'm getting these errors:

Error Log

```
SEVERE: path to 'jrt:/com.scholarly/assets/databases/local_database.db': 'C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Scholarly CBT\jrt:' does not exist
Nov 09, 2023 3:47:30 PM com.scholarly.MainApplication log
SEVERE: com.scholarly.merged.module@0.3/org.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(Unknown Source)
Nov 09, 2023 3:47:30 PM com.scholarly.MainApplication log
SEVERE: com.scholarly.merged.module@0.3/org.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
Nov 09, 2023 3:47:30 PM com.scholarly.MainApplication log
SEVERE: com.scholarly.merged.module@0.3/org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Connection.<init>(Unknown Source)
Nov 09, 2023 3:47:30 PM com.scholarly.MainApplication log
SEVERE: com.scholarly.merged.module@0.3/org.sqlite.jdbc4.JDBC4Connection.<init>(Unknown Source)
Nov 09, 2023 3:47:30 PM com.scholarly.MainApplication log
SEVERE: com.scholarly.merged.module@0.3/org.sqlite.JDBC.createConnection(Unknown Source)
Nov 09, 2023 3:47:30 PM com.scholarly.MainApplication log
SEVERE: com.scholarly.merged.module@0.3/org.sqlite.JDBC.connect(Unknown Source)
Nov 09, 2023 3:47:30 PM com.scholarly.MainApplication log
SEVERE: java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
Nov 09, 2023 3:47:30 PM com.scholarly.MainApplication log
SEVERE: java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
Nov 09, 2023 3:47:30 PM com.scholarly.MainApplication log
SEVERE: com.scholarly@0.3/com.scholarly.data.util.DbConnection.getDbConnection(Unknown Source)
```

Here's the code throwing the error:

```
private static final String TAG = "DbConnection: ";
private static final String location = MainApplication.class.getResource("/assets/databases/local_database.db").getPath();
private static final String DATABASE_URL = "jdbc:sqlite:"+location;

private static Connection connection;

public static Connection getDbConnection() {
    try {
        if (connection == null) {
            MainApplication.logInfo("Database Connecting..");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DATABASE_URL, "", "");

            System.out.println(TAG + "Connection created successfully: " + connection.toString());
            MainApplication.logInfo(TAG + "Connection created successfully: " + connection.toString());
        } else {
            System.out.println(TAG + "Retrieved existing Connection : " + connection);
            MainApplication.logInfo(TAG + "Retrieved existing Connection : " + connection);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        MainApplication.log(e);
    }
    return connection;
}
```

Comment: A JAR is read-only. You cannot write into the JAR’s contained files. Create/copy your database files outside the JAR.

Comment: A database migration tool like Flyway or Liquibase might help you in setting up that externalized database.

Comment: Hello @BasilBourque the database in my case is a local SQLite file that is bundled into a JavaFX application. How can we create/copy the SQLite files outside the JAR. Just checked out Flyway and Liquibase, not sure of how to go about it.

Comment: Either (a) bundle an initial database within your app, and copy the file out to a location on the user's machine, or (b) create a database file at a location on the user's machine. After that, you may want to use Flyway/Liquibase to run your SQL scripts to create tables, columns, indexes, etc. to prepare your database for use.

Comment: Access folders and files using the Java NIO.2 framework. Oracle provides [Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html) and [Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/io/index.html). And search Stack Overflow and the web for more info. But be aware that an enormous amount of file I/o articles and posts you'll find are outdated, written before Java NIO and NIO.2. The newer classes make this work *much* simpler.

Comment: [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73927071/copy-external-resource-files-after-building-javafx-app-with-maven) for Basil’s suggestion: “a) bundle an initial database within your app, and copy the file out to a location on the user's machine,”.

Answer (score 3):

If your SQLite database is a *resource*, then the JDBC URL should look similar to:

```
jdbc:sqlite::resource:assets/databases/local_database.db
```

Assuming you're using the https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc driver. See [`USAGE.md`](https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/blob/master/USAGE.md) for more information. If your code is modular, make sure your database resource's package is `opens` *unconditionally*.

That said, resources are read-only. If you want a writable database, then you'll have to either:

1. Extract the database at run-time. Make sure to do this only if the database has not already been extracted lest you overwrite it and lose data.
2. Let the SQLite driver create a new database at run-time. If I'm not mistaken, the file will be created automatically if it does not already exist, at least by default. But you'll have to run initialization SQL/scripts (e.g., `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ...`) either once every time your application is started or only if the file did not previously exist.

Both options require you have a "known location" for the external database file. Now, you could try the working directory, but that assumes that the working directory is both writable and unchanging between application instances. A typically writable and more deterministic location is needed. A common place that should work across operating systems is a directory in the user's home directory. You can get the home directory with `System.getProperty("user.home")`. Though since you are using `jpackage` for deployment, you might want to add a way to configure more appropriate OS-specific locations, such as a directory under `%LOCALAPPDATA%` on Windows.

Here's an example of a class that extracts the database resource when needed. It also ensures that only one `Connection` is open at any given time and encourages non-parallel use of the database, assuming you ensure you only have one instance of the class at a time.

```java
package com.example;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UncheckedIOException;
import java.nio.file.FileAlreadyExistsException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;
import org.sqlite.SQLiteDataSource;

public class SQLiteDatabase implements AutoCloseable {

    private static final String DB_RESOURCE_NAME = "/assets/databases/local_database.db";

    @FunctionalInterface
    public interface SQLFunction<R> {

        R execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException;
    }

    private final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();

    private final Path dbFile;
    private final SQLiteDataSource source;

    private Connection connection;
    private boolean open = true;
    private boolean extracted;

    public SQLiteDatabase(Path dbFile) {
        this.dbFile = dbFile.toAbsolutePath().normalize();
        extracted = Files.exists(dbFile);

        source = new SQLiteDataSource();
        source.setUrl("jdbc:sqlite:" + this.dbFile);
        source.setEnforceForeignKeys(true);
    }

    public <R> R execute(SQLFunction<R> function) throws SQLException {
        Objects.requireNonNull(function);
        lock.lock();
        try {
            ensureOpen();
            extractDatabase();

            if (connection == null || connection.isClosed()) {
                connection = source.getConnection();
            }
            return function.execute(connection);
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    private void ensureOpen() {
        if (!open) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("SQLiteDatabase has been closed.");
        }
    }

    private void extractDatabase() {
        if (!extracted) {
            try (var input = SQLiteDatabase.class.getResourceAsStream(DB_RESOURCE_NAME)) {
                Files.copy(input, dbFile);
                extracted = true;
            } catch (FileAlreadyExistsException ex) {
                extracted = true;
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                throw new UncheckedIOException("Unable to extract SQLite database resource", ex);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws SQLException {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            if (open) {
                open = false;
                if (connection != null) {
                    connection.close();
                    connection = null;
                }
            }
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

Using the above class might look like:

```java
package com.example;

import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    /*
     * WARNING: This code will create a directory in your user home directory and does
     *          not make any attempt to delete it. The directory name will be ".app_name"
     *          unless the code is modified. Inside the ".app_name" directory will be a
     *          "local_database.db" file.
     * 
     *          The SQLiteDatabase class assumes there's a SQLite database resource located
     *          at "/assets/databases/local_database.db". If that resource does not exist then
     *          this code will fail.
     */
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        var dbFile = Path.of(System.getProperty("user.home"), ".app_name", "local_database.db");
        Files.createDirectories(dbFile.getParent()); // parent directories must exist

        try (var db = new SQLiteDatabase(dbFile)) {
            List<?> data = db.execute(conn -> {
                try (var stat = conn.createStatement()) {
                    var entities = new ArrayList<>();
                    var set = stat.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM xxx");
                    while (set.next()) {
                        // get attributes, create entity instance, add to entities list
                    }
                    return entities;
                }
            });
            data.forEach(System.out::println);
        }
    }
}
```

Though ideally, you'd be hiding the use of `SQLiteDatabase` behind a repository or data access object (DAO) interface. And of course, using a migration tool/library, a JDBC-wrapper library, and/or an ORM framework may make your life easier in general.